# VueJS: dynamic component loses it`s props after reloading

Tags: vue.js

I have a django rest_framework as a server and vuejs for a client side. There is an index page like '/' where i`m using v-for to iterate an array of objects to show some item's cards. Each card has a button to the '/info'(which is dynamically changed with /:slug in a router) like so:

```
...
<RouterLink :to="{name: 'contentItemInfo', params: {item: item, slug: item.slug} }">
   <button class="card-button btn fade-in">
      ...
   </button>
</RouterLink>
...
```

Then, when we press the button, we are going to '/:slug' and passing the item param to props, using it like so:

```
...
<video class="video" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop :src="item.trailer"/>
<h3 class="video-info-h3 px-5 py-1 rounded">{{ item.title }}</h3>
<h5 class="video-info-h5 px-5 py-1 rounded">{{ item.subtitle }}</h5>
<p class="video-info-p px-5 py-1 text-wrap rounded">{{ item.description }}</p>
...

export default {
  name: "ContentItemInfo",
  components: {Footer, Navbar},
  props: [
    'item'
  ],
}
```

Works for now, but when i reload the page, all the content disappeare and got undefined of all item`s values

How should i make it work after reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing complex objects by route param only works in-memory. Once you reload the page, the only data you have is strings from the URL. You'll have to load the `item` data from your backend for fresh page loads.

Try something like this, making the `item` prop optional and loading the data if it's not set

```js
export default {
  name: "ContentItemInfo",
  components: {Footer, Navbar},
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    slug: String // set from the route param
  }
  data: vm => ({
    video: vm.item // initialise a local copy so you can update it if required
  }),
  async created () {
    if (this.video === null) {
      // just guessing with this bit
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/video-for-slug/${encodeURIComponent(this.slug)}`)
      this.video = data
    }
  }
}
```

and your template

```html
<div v-if="video">
  <video
    class="video"
    type="video/mp4"
    autoplay
    loop
    :src="video.trailer"
  />
  <h3 class="video-info-h3 px-5 py-1 rounded">{{ video.title }}</h3>
  <h5 class="video-info-h5 px-5 py-1 rounded">{{ video.subtitle }}</h5>
  <p class="video-info-p px-5 py-1 text-wrap rounded">{{ video.description }}</p>
</div>
<p v-else>Loading...</p>
```

In the above, I assumed that your routes are passing params as props. If not, see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: thanks man, seems like a good soltion; the only things a would also know is whether i could get /:slug  from search bar or it`ll be 404?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means