# How to pass data with programmatic navigation Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```js
const editUser = (e) => {
  dataRow.push({
    firstName: e.detail.firstName,
    lastName: e.detail.secondName,         
    emailAddress: e.detail.emailAddress
  })
  router.push({name: 'editPage', params: { dataRow }})
  console.log(dataRow)
}
```

I want to pass dataRow to another component to edit the user details. dataRow is being assigned correctly and it is showing in the console but I am not sure how to push it to the edit page. Below is my codes for the router.

```js
{
  path: '/edit', 
  name: 'editPage', 
  component: () => import('./pages/UsersEdit.vue'), 
  beforeEnter: authGuard, 
  props: true 
},
```

how do I pass and receive the data between the components?

and below is my code for calling the props in my export default and html

```
<div>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" v-model="dataRow.firstName">
</div>

props: {
dataRow: {
  type: Object
}
```

},

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS: dynamic component loses it`s props after reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929824/vuejs-dynamic-component-loses-its-props-after-reloading)

Comment: the only way I can think is using params?, but my question is why do not you use vuex?

Comment: @Phil Yes, the link you referred to me helps. Much thanks! However, my dataRow is displaying as undefined in the child component.. Any ideas?

Comment: That entirely depends on the content of your component which you have not shown. Also, why is `dataRow` an array?

Comment: @Phil I have added more codes from my child component and how I call the props. Is setting it an array not right in setting the props?

Comment: An array seems an odd choice if you're expecting an object (as defined in your `props` and as indicated in your use of `dataRow.firstName`). That's why your code isn't working

Answer (score -1):

- you have to create a shared component / service file where your shared variable which is being used by more than one component will be stored
- Call that component in both of your components where you want to fetch and update data
- It will maintain its state even if data is changed